# Unexpected flowId in Spring Web Flow

Tags: spring-webflow

I use Shibboleth, and it uses Spring Web Flow. In my environment, a mismatch between the expected flow id and the registered flow id occurs.

Shibboleth tries to execute a flow but I get this error:

```
Uncaught runtime exception 
org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.NoSuchFlowDefinition:
No flow definition 'authn/foo' found at 
org.springframework.webflow.definition.registry.
FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.getFlowDefinitionHolder
(FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.java:123)
```

Here is what [this piece of code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow/blob/master/spring-webflow/src/main/java/org/springframework/webflow/definition/registry/FlowDefinitionRegistryImpl.java#L99-L100) outputs in the log:

```
Registering flow definition 'file[D:¥Shibboleth¥IdP¥flows¥authn¥foo¥foo-flow.xml]'
under id 'D:/Shibboleth/IdP/flows/authn/foo'
```

My environment is Japanese Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with IBM Webshpere 8.5.

It looks like somewhere Web Flow is failing to deduct correct flow id, and just uses the entire path of the file for it. As you can see there is a mixture of `¥`(this is what is displayed in Japanese Windows instead of slash) and `/` involved. I don't know if this causes the problem though.

Is there a way to solve this problem or somehow to force the correct flow name (e.g. can I just right flow id in the foo-flow.xml)?

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this [FlowDefinitionResourceFactory.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-webflow/blob/e77fdb6e5fd4193c8a2eb7ee56ba5fe543cf2ae1/spring-webflow/src/main/java/org/springframework/webflow/config/FlowDefinitionResourceFactory.java):

That guy is responsible for finding flow files on the file system and parsing/converting them to flow definitions.

From glancing at the code I cannot tell where the operating system defined `'/'` is being inserted but I suspect the spring String/ResourceResolver utility classes in **FlowDefinitionResourceFactory.java** are deriving the operating system `'¥'`. Try to step into that class and see if you can isolate where it is exactly happening at.

Regardless, as you stated this is an environmental issue. I'm not sure what you can configure (on SWF) to change this behavior other than converting the OS language settings to English? Which I am assume is an unacceptable answer. You might be able to @Override some internal SWF or spring utility classes... but I suspect spring/swf are behaving as expected and the input/config (i.e environment) being fed into them is what is the problem... my guess is any possible "solution" will involve @Overriding or 'hacking' something to fit SWF in your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I found the place where I can define names for flows and map them to XML files. In case of Shibboleth IdP it was `webflow-config.xml` file, though they do not recommend to touch this file. But I had no other choice (so far).